# Confidence interval of a sample without standard deviation

Tags: calculus, statistics

I have a problem to find the $95\%$ confidence interval.
I have $8$ randomly selected bottles with values:
$15.2, 15.7, 15.9, 15.9, 15.1, 15.5, 15.5, 15.7, 15.3$
And the necessary quantile is $2.36$. That's all I get from the text.
I calculated the mean which is $15.53$ and the standard deviation which is $0.28$ but now I am stuck.
How can I find the $95\%$ confidence interval?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the confidence interval is $$\bar x\pm t_{{\alpha\over 2},df}\cdot\frac s{\sqrt n}$$ where

$\bar x$ is the sample mean

$s$ is the sample standard deviation

$n$ is the sample size

and $\alpha$ is $1$ minus the confidence level

Comment: What you wrote is correct (+1). But the question has discrepancies and gaps, so my Answer digs a little deeper. Who knows if that will be of additional help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat sketchy as it stands. For one thing you say
there are eight observations, but I count nine. (Is it possible you
wrote "15.5" twice, when it occurs once in the book? For the *nine* observations you give, I got
$\bar X = 15.53$ and $S = 0.291.$)

Maybe if you look
at the context of the question in your book you can find more details.
Here is what I can make of your question.

You are to assume that the 9 observations come from a normal population,
with unknown population mean $\mu$ and population standard deviation $\sigma.$
You are to make a 95% t confidence interval for $\mu,$ which (as @browngreen says) is of the form $$\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$$ where $\bar X$ is the sample mean,
$S$ is the sample SD, $n$ is the sample size, and $t^*$ is the given 'quantile' 2.306 (not 2.36).

You can find from printed tables of Student's t distribution that 2.306 cuts
2.5% of the probability from the upper tail of this distribution, with
degrees of freedom $\nu = n - 1 = 8.$  (If there are really $n = 8$ observations,
then $\nu = 7$ and the quantile is $2.365.$)

If you plug all of the correct quantities into the displayed formula, you will
get the required 95% CI.

---

In R statistical software, the procedure `t.test` computes such a confidence
interval, using *all nine* observations. I got the output below (with irrelevant output redacted `...`).

```
x = c(15.2,15.7,15.9, 15.9,15.1,15.5, 15.5,15.7,15.3)
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 15.53333
## 0.2915476

t.test(x)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 159.84, df = 8, ...
...
95 percent confidence interval:
  15.30923 15.75744
...
```

*Note:* Omitting the second 15.5 and using the remaining eight observations, I get the sample mean 15.54, sample SD
0.311, and CI $(15.277, 15.798).$